# Get user game stats in steam

Tags: steam, steam-web-api, steamworks-api

I am trying to get user game stats. First, I am trying to do like this:

```
http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUserStats/GetUserStatsForGame/v0002/?appid=570&key=949DDA17D1A94CB9D387F2BE0727EB5F&steamid=76561198140055626&include_appinfo=1
```

For dota I just have this response:

```
{ "playerstats": { "steamID": "76561198140055626", "gameName": "[STAGING] DotA 2" } }
```

So my question is, how I can get all public game stats from `Dota2,CS:GO,PUBG,etc.`? Because this method doesn't work with `Dota2`?

Answer (score 1):

The question is fully related to steam api.

There is public online web application ([Better Steam Web API](http://steamwebapi.azurewebsites.net/)), which explains the steam api in more details.

Please, take a the examples presented there.

I guess you can find the one you need.

Comment: lost 2 days to find something and this method `http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUserStats/GetUserStatsForGame/v0002/` all that i can find